# PNG image corrupted when saved

Tags: python, excel

I have code that iterates through Excel objects in Python and can find each graph and saves it as a png. however, when I run the script and the images get saved, when I try and Then I view they are corrupted.

[image: Code Picture]

I try and save them as either a png or a jpeg. I also need to use this method cannot use the raw data to create graphs.

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as an image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are only saving a chart object with the name of a png file.

try adding the line:

```
chartObject.Copy
```

before the line where you do the export.